# Error when install dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 on CentOS 8 - Folder [/usr/share/dotnet/host/fxr] does not contain any version-numbered child folders

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, centos8

Like as dotnet/dotnet-docker#1537
but I have same error on CenOS 8 (not Docker) on standalone machine.
Clean new CentOS 8 with latest updates on 23 dec 2020.
in console:

`sudo dnf install aspnetcore-runtime-3.1` - OK

`dotnet` - OK (shows using manual)

`dotnet --info` - error:

`A fatal error occurred, the folder [/usr/share/dotnet/host/fxr] does not contain any version-numbered child folders`

`dotnet --list-runtimes` - error:
`A fatal error occurred, the folder [/usr/share/dotnet/host/fxr] does not contain any version-numbered child folders`

`dotnet *.dll` - error:
`A fatal error occurred, the folder [/usr/share/dotnet/host/fxr] does not contain any version-numbered child folders`

the folder `/usr/share/dotnet/host/fxr` is really empty. Trying to install SDK - no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem after updating my system to Fedora 32. The problem was, that I had installed dotnet-runtime-2.1 before, but Fedora 32 comes with 3.1 included.

If your dotnet application is compatible with 3.1, you can simply uninstall the old runtime. That's how I did it:

1. Check installed dotnet runtimes:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep dotnet
dotnet-runtime-2.1-2.1.12-1.x86_64
dotnet-runtime-deps-2.1-2.1.12-1.x86_64
dotnet-hostfxr-2.1-2.1.12-1.x86_64
dotnet-host-3.1.10-1.fc32.x86_64
```

In my case, version 2.1 was installed by myself. 3.1 was installed by the system (tagged with fc32)

2. Remove the old version:

```
dnf remove dotnet-runtime-2.1
```

3. To install 2.1, I had to add the microsoft repo before, which is not needed anymore:

```
rm /etc/yum.repos.d/microsoft-prod.repo
```

4. For some unknown reason, uninstalling 2.1 also uninstalled 3.1. Install it as you usually would:

```
 dnf install dotnet-runtime-3.1
```

5. `dotnet --info` should work again.

For more information or if your application requires dotnet 2.1:

https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/4655

Answer (score 3):

If the dotnet sdk is version 5.0

step 1.- Remove sdk

```
sudo dnf remove dotnet-sdk-5.0
```

step 2.- remove folders

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/dotnet
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/dotnet
sudo rm -rf /etc/yum.repos.d/microsoft-prod.repo
```

step 4.- Clean and upgrade.

```
sudo dnf clean all
sudo dnf upgrade
```

step 5.- Reboot system

```
sudo init 6
```

step 6.- Finally

```
sudo dnf install dotnet-sdk-5.0
```

Comment: With dotnet 5.0 all works perfectly, but answer is for 3.1